# Probability question of die throwing

Tags: probability

How many 6 show up when throwing 5 dice?

This is expressed by
$\Pr(X=x)=(5/6)^{5-x}\cdot (1/6)^
x\cdot\binom{5}{x}$

Then I got the following

$0\cdot \Pr(X=0)=0$

$1\cdot \Pr(X=1)=0.4$

$2\cdot \Pr(X=2)=0.32$

$3\cdot \Pr(X=3)=0.09$

$4\cdot \Pr(X=4)=0.0012$

$5\cdot \Pr(X=5)=0.0065$

$E(X)=0.825$, but my book says $E(x)=1$.  Where is the mistake?

Comment: You have equals signs here for things which are not equalities.  $0.825\neq 0.8333333\cdots = \frac{5}{6}$.  Similarly, $5\cdot \frac{1}{6^5}=\frac{5}{7776}\approx 0.000643004115\cdots\neq 0.0065$

Comment: Now... if the book says that $E[X]=1$... are you sure you read the question correctly?  Are you sure that it isn't asking the number or $6$'s that show up when throwing *six* dice?

Answer (score 1):

The answer of your textbook is wrong! And the proof is very simple:

Your random variable is a binomial $X\sim Bin\left(5;\frac{1}{6}\right)$ with expectation

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=5\cdot \frac{1}{6}=\frac{5}{6}$$

Comment: @Surb sorry I was finishing to answer when I unitentionally pushed "Entry key"

Comment: It may be worth mentioning linearity of expectation and showing how to calculate the expected value this way rather than citing the result for binomial distributions which is otherwise just going to be "*one more thing to memorize*" which might compound the frustrations of the average student.

Comment: @JMoravitz : of course I respect your authoritative opinion (+1), but when the O.P. wrote down correctly the expression of $P(X=x)$ I think he knows the mean of the Binomial that is one of the basic things that remain in mind of any student...also in my mind, having stopped my studies about 30 years ago...